# Back mechanism in Fragment

Tags: android

I have One activity and the code in activity.xml is as below..

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_margin"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/big_margin"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/small_big_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_big_height"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/act_standing_area_add_transporter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/act_standing_area_add_transporter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/search" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/actv_location_select_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/search_location"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/large_margin"
        android:singleLine="true"

        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_big_text"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container_select_city"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the question is..On the creation of my activity i add MyFragment1 in Frame layout. MyFragment1 contains recyclerView. On the selection of item in recyclerView i add MyFragment2. Now on back press i want to show MyFragment1..please give your suggestions.

Comment: Ok show me your java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're asking for suggestion, I can give you one. I had this kind of flow implemented in some of my applications.

In your activity take a `boolean` flag `isReturnedFromDetailFragment` and set it `true` initially.

```
private boolean isReturnedFromDetailFragment = true;
```

When `MyFragment2` is being replaced, set the `boolean` value to `false`.

Now in `onBackPressed` function in your `Activity`, check if `isReturnedFromDetailFragment` is `true`. If not, then replace `MyFragment1` in the `FrameLayout` and the set the `boolean` value again to `true`.